# How to pass variable from script 1 to script 2 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq

I need help please.
I have 2 scripts. The first script consumes from RabbitMQ and I need to send the body received to a variable in script 2.
However, the variable remains empty. I think that script 1 maybe is calling script 2 before the value is received from RabbitMQ?

How can I achieve this? Thanks

script 1

```
import pika
import time
from script2 import strQueue

class ReceiveFromMQ(object):

    def __init__(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxxx', 'xxxx')
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('xxxx', xxx, 'xxx',
                                               credentials)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self.channel.basic_consume(
            queue='queue',
            on_message_callback=self.on_response,
            auto_ack=True)
        self.response = None
        self.channel.start_consuming()
 

    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        self.response = body.decode()
        strQueue = body.decode()
        print(" [x] Received %r" % body.decode())
        # getMsg(body.decode())
        time.sleep(body.count(b'.'))
        print(" [x] Done")
        print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
        return self.response

    def call(self):
        self.response = None

        self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)
        print(str(self.response))
        return str(self.response)


receive_mq = ReceiveFromMQ()
response = receive_mq.call()
print(response)
```

script 2

```
import requests
import json
 
strQueue = None

 
# Function Authenticate
def httpAuthenticate (in_apiusers, in_apipass, in_Tenant, in_URL):
    try:
        print('retrieve token...')
        url = in_URL
        payload = json.dumps({
            "password": str(in_apipass),
            "usernameOrEmailAddress": str(in_apiusers),
            "tenancyName": str(in_Tenant)
        })
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        json_object = json.loads(response.text)
        print('token code: ' + str(response.status_code))
        return str(json_object["result"])
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Fail:'


# Function:Add Queue Item on Uipath Orchestrator
def httpAddQueueItems(in_URL, in_Token, in_QueueName, in_strjson):
    try:
        print('add queue item...')
        url = in_URL
        payload = json.dumps({
            "itemData": {
                "Priority": "Normal",
                "Name": str(in_QueueName),
                "SpecificContent": {
                    "in_pjsorequest": in_strpjson
                },
                "Reference": "ggg"
            }
        })
        headers = {
            'X-UIPATH-OrganizationUnitId': '',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + in_Token
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
         
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 'Fail'


# CONSTANTS
 
OnPremuser = "xxxx"
OnPrempass = "xxx!"
OnPremtenant = "Default"
OnPremUrlAuth = "xxxx"
OnPremUrlAddQueue = "https://xxxx"
OnPremQueue = "JSON"
OnPremPJSON = strQueue

OnPremtoken = httpAuthenticate(OnPremuser, OnPrempass, OnPremtenant, OnPremUrlAuth)
httpAddQueueItems(OnPremUrlAddQueue, OnPremtoken, OnPremQueue, OnPremJSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What you are trying to achieve is not possible in this way since you are
> trying to access a shared variable (Race Condition).
> Moreover, only one bytecode instruction can be executed at a time, mean to
> say, only one CPU bound task can be run at a time.

P.S:- It can be achieved by running a consumer for the RabbitMQ producer and then assign the json received to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Not sure I understand what you mean. Can you maybe please give an example?

Comment: file1.py
temp_list = []
for i in range(1000):
      temp_list.append(i)


file2.py
from file1 import temp_list
for i in temp_list:
      print(i) # do something with it
Running both file at same time will result in accessing the same variable at same time. as this operation is completely tied to a CPU, it'll activate the GIL (global Interpreter lock) which will not let it happen.

Comment: https://carbon.now.sh/?bg=rgba%28171%2C+184%2C+195%2C+1%29&t=seti&wt=none&l=auto&width=680&ds=true&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=true&wa=true&pv=56px&ph=56px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=2x&wm=false&code=file1.py%250A%250Atemp_list%2520%253D%2520%255B%255D%250Afor%2520i%2520in%2520range%281000%29%253A%250A%2520%2520%2509temp_list.append%28i%29%250A%2520%250A%2520%250Afile2.py%250Afrom%2520file1%2520import%2520temp_list%250Afor%2520i%2520in%2520temp_list%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520print%28i%29